# create subversion branch or tag without a working copy

Tags: svn

Is it possible to create a subversion branch or tag from a certain revision directly without having a working copy? I am using TortoiseSVN but I don't see this option in the repository browser! Isn't it good practice to use a certain revision for branching instead of a working copy?

If not I guess I'll just have to do a complete checkout into a temporary directory simply for creating a branch/tag.

(Details: The reason I ask is that I have an SVN project with a "trunk" directory that is logically subdivided into a few parts (directories) that in turn contain several subprojects/modules in subdirectories. Because the subprojects often change together I wish to branch/tag all of these at once. Unfortunately my IDE (Eclipse) cannot handle this hierarchical project structure. So I simply checkout each subproject directory directly as a project in my Eclipse workspace. This means I have several "sub working copies" and cannot use Eclipse to create such a branch/tag directly. What I would like to do is to create a branch/tag of the entire trunk which can be imported into a separate workspace for the specific branch or tag.)

Comment: Note that I realise that the setup I described is far from ideal. Merging would be a hell if you don't have a full working directory of trunk. The solution is to not checkout individual projects directly from SVN into the Eclipse workspace, but to create a full checkout of trunk and then import the projects into the workspace (without copying the contents). Even though Eclipse will not present projects in a tree structure, it will still have a tree structure on the file system and you will have a real working copy.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can using [SVN COPY](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html) operation. Another benefit of this is that all existing changes history will be kept. Doing copy through a local copy you can easily lose all previous change history.

And you can use Eclipse for this task as well. Do it through SVN Perspective > SVN Repositories view. Find your trunk, right click and select "copy" from the context menu. Then find correct destination and "paste". That would result in performing SVN Copy operation on the repository side.

Answer (score 3):

My excuses I didn't look well enough! The answer is that there is a "copy to..." command. Right click trunk -> copy to... -> replace "trunk" with "tags/yourversion". When you want to create a tag for an older revision, you can specify the revision by clicking on the "HEAD" button at the top right of the window to switch to that revision first. (Review the logs to find out the right revision number.)